# Side bar is not showing when tab is enable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a surprise problem with `woocommerce`. I have a sidebar widget for single product. 
But if tab is display then footer and sidebar is not working. I found that, 
if I deleted this line of code:

`<?php call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ) ?>`

from `single-product/tabs/tabs.php` then sidebar and footer are displaying. But tab is not!

Also from `content-single-product.php` file, if I remove this hook `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary`, then footer and sidebar are displaying. 
I am using `child-theme`.

What else can I do?

Comment: Also if i remove "review " tab , then its displaying sidebar and footer, which means there is issue with review tab..

Comment: Use Edit to edit your question instead of commenting.